# Using Puppeteer, how to get Chrome DevTools' "Network" tab's timing information?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Below is a screenshot of me accessing https://www.ted.com and inspecting the Google Chrome DevTools' "Network" tab, and viewing the Timing data for the root & child requests.

[image]

**How can I get all of the above timing data programatically using Puppeteer?** Ideally, it would look like this JSON structure:

```
{
    name: "www.ted.com",
    queueTime: 0,
    startedTime: 1.93,
    stalledTime: 4.59,
    dnsLookupTime: 10.67,
    initialConnectionTime: <the number of milliseconds>,
    ...
},
{
    name: <the next child request>,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to check out HAR (HTTP Archive) files, which is what you would create by [saving the data](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/blob/master/docs/network.md#saving-network-data) via Chrome.

**Quotation what a HAR file is** ([source](https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary/har-file/)):

> The HAR file format is an evolving standard and the information contained within it is both flexible and extensible. You can expect a HAR file to include a breakdown of timings including:
>
> 1. How long it takes to fetch DNS information
> 2. How long each object takes to be requested
> 3. How long it takes to connect to the server
> 4. How long it takes to transfer assets from the server to the browser of each object
>
> The data is stored as a JSON document and extracting meaning from the
>   low-level data is not always easy. But with practice a HAR file can
>   quickly help you identify the key performance problems with a web
>   page, letting you efficiently target your development efforts at areas
>   of your site that will deliver the greatest results.

There are libraries like [puppeteer-har](https://github.com/Everettss/puppeteer-har) and [chrome-har](https://github.com/sitespeedio/chrome-har) which can create HAR files by using puppeteer.

**Code sample** (for [puppeteer-har](https://github.com/Everettss/puppeteer-har#usage), quote from the page)

```js
const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);
await har.start({ path: 'results.har' });

await page.goto('http://example.com');

await har.stop();
```

Comment: If have multiple workflows, like login, place an order and logout & want to measure it in every page do I need to place this in every page similarly like 

`const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);
await har.start({ path: 'login.har' });
await page.goto('http://loging');
await har.stop();
await har.start ({path: 'placeOrder.har'});
await page.goto ({'http://placeorder.com'});
await har.stop();
await har.start ({path : 'logout.har'});
await page.goto ({'http://logout'});
await har.stop();`

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK You can produce a HAR file per page or for multiple pages. Both works. AFAIK it only depends on where you call start and stop.

Answer (score 3):

HAR files are a good option, but if want something a bit more custom you can use [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) to record request timing data by navigating to the page you wish to analyze, and tapping into the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

```js
(async function() {
  // launch in headless mode & create a new page
  const browser = await pptr.launch({
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // attach cdp session to page
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send('Debugger.enable');
  await client.send('Debugger.setAsyncCallStackDepth', { maxDepth: 32 });

  // enable network
  await client.send('Network.enable');
  // attach callback to network response event
  await client.on('Network.responseReceived', (params) => {
    const { response: { timing } } = params;
    /*
     * See: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol
     * /tot/Network/#type-ResourceTiming for complete list of
     * timing data available under 'timing'
     */
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.ted.com/', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });

  // cleanup
  await browser.close();
})();
```

For your case, you can listen on the `Network.responseReceived` event, and parse out the `responseTime` parameter, nested within the `response` property on the response object provided in the event listener callback. Their documentation on the interfaces is quite good. I'll list them below:

---

#### Chrome DevTools Protocol Docs

Data you can expect to receive from every `Network.responseReceived` event callback: [Network.responseReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived).

More specific response-related data, in the `response` property: [Network.Response](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-Response).

And, finally, the nested request timing data you are looking for, under `timing`: [Network.ResourceTiming](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-ResourceTiming).

---

You may also want to check out the `Network.requestWillBeSent` interface. You will be able to match up requests and responses by `requestId`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can also get this information without the HAR file.

Using [performance.getEntriesByType("resource")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType)

```
// Obtain PerformanceEntry objects for resources    
const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
      await page.evaluate(() =>
        JSON.stringify(performance.getEntriesByType("resource"))
      )
    );
    
// Optionally filter resource results to find your specifics - ex. filters on URL
const imageRequests = performanceTiming.filter((e) =>
  e.name.endsWith("/images")
);

console.log("Image Requests " , imageRequests)
```